# Drupal Commerce: Price based on width / height calculation

Tags: commerce

I think has been discussed somewhere but i cant find it again...
i know complicated attribute pricing is possible with Rules, and something about custom line items, but i wonder how to accomplish a price in the case where

1. something has a size - width, height, etc. Price per inch.
2. There are different materials at different prices per inch.
3. the same product can add multiple items (First is 23"x34"x6" and the second 23"x34"x10")
4. A fixed price is set when a second level is added. (combination fee)

Is there anyway to do this with commerce? The only other idea I had was a custom javascript calculator that passes the price into the price field, but that seems to hacky.

Comment: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/3626/variable_pricing_based_range_values

Comment: I posted an answer here http://drupal.org/node/1920014,  let me know if thats enough info or if you need more.

Comment: THanks!! Ive replied over there. Maybe the actual question is being revised to, to find the ultimate solution :)